# Is it possible to work with a variable before its creation?

Tags: python

I want to create a function that plots a 2-dimensional system of differential equations, but if I call the function with a parameter like 2*x + 3*y I'll obviously run into an exception because I have not defined x and y at the time of execution.

In code, I want to do something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def streamplot(xdot, ydot, xxrange, yyrange):
    """Displays the stream plot of a two-dimensional system of equations."""
    x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0,xxrange,1),np.arange(0,yyrange,1)
    plt.streamplot(x, y, xdot, ydot)
    plt.show()
```

but evidently xdot and ydot will depend on x and y which are not assigned yet. I think it should be possible to catch the exception Python will create when the function is executed and create these variables at that time, but there should be a simpler way of doing this, right?

Comment: `xdot` and `ydot` are inputs to the function. So they are assigned?

Comment: What I wish is that xdot can be 2*x + 3*y without the user having defined x and y previously. Something like a placeholder until I define them in the function code, as in the sixth line of code in the post above.

Comment: What is your actual use case?

Comment: I wish for a way to define xdot and ydot (which is a function in the mathematical sense) before defining its variables, x and y. That is because I want to define x and y as a meshgrid without the user having to define that himself before calling the function.

Comment: I think indeed xdot and ydot should be functions, rather than variables. Once x and y are known you call them on x and y. In Python you can pass in functions just as easy as variables. Probably lambda functions will be handy here, when calling streamplot.

Comment: Functions are first order citizens in Python. This means you can not just define functions, but assign them as variables, and pass them as arguments to other functions. They are truly objects. You can for example write a plotting function which takes a function as one of its arguments. Then you do `def f(x):` and pass `f` to the plotting function. Might this achieve what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like xdot and ydot are functions rather than variables.
You can pass in functions as parameters to other functions:

```
import math

def applyTwice (f, x):
    return f (f (x))

print (applyTwice (math.sqrt, 16))

print (applyTwice (lambda x: 2 * x, 10))

'''
Output:
2.0
40
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to describe math equations in python, you can try using simpy:

```
from sympy import *
x = Symbol('x')
y = Symbol('y')
x+y+x-y
>>>2*x
```

you could define `xdot` and `ydot` as simpy Symbols.

more details here: https://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/sympy.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's taking what Jacques de Hooge said in his answer and I in the comments, but making it more specific to your code. Note how `f` can be any function from R^2 to R^2, and can be passed to your `streamplot` function.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x, y):
    return x + y, x*y

def streamplot(f, x_min=0, x_max=1, y_min=0, y_max=1,
        x_num_divisions=100, y_num_divisions=100):

    """Displays the stream plot of a two-dimensional system of equations."""

    x, y = np.meshgrid(
        np.linspace(x_min, x_max, x_num_divisions),
        np.linspace(y_min, y_max, y_num_divisions)
    )
    xdot, ydot = f(x, y)
    plt.streamplot(x, y, xdot, ydot)
    plt.show()

streamplot(f)
```

[image]